# AIX: how to see the contents of a service?

Tags: services, aix

On Linux when I want to see contents of systemd service I run:

```
systemctl status myservice
```

I see the XML, I do cat and I see which command, script and vars use this service.

On Solaris I use:

```
svcs -xv myservice
```

On AIX, I see the nimclient service

```
lssrc -a|grep nimclient
lssrc -s nimclient
```

How to see the contents (which scripts it uses, detail of command, etc) of the nimclient service on AIX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is:

```
odmget -q subsysname=nimclient SRCsubsys
```

... which outputs a stanza that includes information about the path to the program and what its input, output and stderr are connected to. The configurable parameters come from the [mkssys command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=m-mkssys-command), which has more information about those parameters.

If the subsystem supports it, you can query its current status in long form:

```
lssrc -l -s nimclient
```

Here's sample `odmget` output from the xntpd service (I don't have a nimclient subsystem handy to show):

```
$ odmget -q subsysname=xntpd SRCsubsys

SRCsubsys:
        subsysname = "xntpd"
        synonym = ""
        cmdargs = ""
        path = "/usr/sbin/xntpd"
        uid = 0
        auditid = 0
        standin = "/dev/console"
        standout = "/dev/console"
        standerr = "/dev/console"
        action = 2
        multi = 0
        contact = 3
        svrkey = 0
        svrmtype = 0
        priority = 20
        signorm = 0
        sigforce = 0
        display = 1
        waittime = 20
        grpname = "tcpip"
```